# Need help in the creation of footer in grid view

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to create footer in a grid view for Android? I have a grid view which displays the images in the net below that I'm using a textview to display `click here to view more images`. My problem is to display the message in the gridview. Please help on regarding this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it below the `GridView`. Have the `GridView` and the "footer" be inside some container (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.) and position them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this in which i fixed on textview in bottom as my footer. while i m displaying list view items.

http://www.techuv.com/layout-with-butoon-and-textview-fixed-in-bottom/